# How to order a table based on null values?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have an `warehouse` table. It has a column named `level`. I want to sort it ascending and if `level` is null then it should sort descending based on `id`.

For example. my table has following records.

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | name      | level |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 1  | osaka     | 3     |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 2  | tokyo     | null  |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 3  | sapporo   | null  |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 4  | nagoya    | 4     |
+----+-----------+-------+
| 5  | hiroshima | 1     |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Firstly based on level column it should sort hiroshima->osaka->nagoya. Rest are null. So they will be sorted descending based on id column. So, it will be sapporo->tokyo.
So, final sorted result will be hiroshima->osaka->nagoya->sapporo->tokyo.

So far I have tried,

```
$warehouses = Warehouse::orderby('level','asc)
                         ->pluck('name');
dd($warehouses);
```

This obviously is not working. But I am not sure about how to move forward. I am using PGSQL.

I have found similar question in SO. I have tried some raw query based on that. Still couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

1. Get all from the table.
2. Using the collected results get all without null levels then sort them.
3. Using the collected results get all with null levels then sort them.
4. Merge the 2 sorted collection results and pluck the name.

```
// 1. Get all from the table.
$warehouses = Wharehouse::all();

// 2. Using the collected results get all without null levels then sort them.
$warehousesWithLevels = $warehouses->where('level', '!=', null)
                                        ->sortBy('level');

// 3. Using the collected results get all with null levels then sort them.
$warehousesWithoutLevels  = $warehouses->where('level', null)
                                        ->sortByDesc('id');

// 4. Merge the 2 sorted collection results and pluck the name.
$warehousesSorted = $warehousesWithLevels->merge($warehousesWithoutLevels)->pluck('name');

dd($warehousesSorted);
```

Or with the Scope I created in the model you can use:

```
Wharehouse::allSortedMyWay();
```

The above has one DB query then works with the collected results.

You can modify the sorting on whatever key best suits your need.

Tested as working with the following results:

```
Collection {#268 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => "hiroshima"
    1 => "osaka"
    2 => "nagoya"
    3 => "sapporo"
    4 => "tokyo"
  ]
}
```

Model I used:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Wharehouse extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'warehouses';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * Fillable fields for a Profile.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'level',
    ];
}

    /**
     * Return all warehousts sorted my way - Quick but not a true query scope.
     *
     * @return collection
     */
    public function scopeAllSortedMyWay()
    {
        $warehouses = Wharehouse::all();

        $warehousesWithLevels = $warehouses->where('level', '!=', null)
                                                ->sortBy('level');

        $warehousesWithoutLevels  = $warehouses->where('level', null)
                                                ->sortByDesc('id');

        return $warehousesWithLevels->merge($warehousesWithoutLevels)->pluck('name');
    }
```

Seeder I used:

```
<?php

use App\Wharehouse;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class WharehouseTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $items = [
            [
                'name'   => 'osaka',
                'level'   => 3,
            ],
            [
                'name'   => 'tokyo',
                'level'   => null,
            ],
            [
                'name'   => 'sapporo',
                'level'   => null,
            ],
            [
                'name'   => 'nagoya',
                'level'   => 4,
            ],
            [
                'name'   => 'hiroshima',
                'level'   => 1,
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $newItem = Wharehouse::where('name', '=', $item['name'])->first();

            if ($newItem === null) {
                $newItem = Wharehouse::create([
                    'name'         => $item['name'],
                    'level'        => $item['level'],
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Migration I used:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateWarehouseTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('warehouses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->integer('level')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('warehouses');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   warehouse
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN level IS null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, level, id;
```

You can [try here](http://tpcg.io/P8KjJB)

Comment: I tried it. It gives sapporo->tokyo at first. They should be at last. How can I force null values to go last? If possible give me eloquent query which I can use in laravel.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try if it giving you desired results.

Comment: It is giving error "Order direction must be "asc" or "desc"."

Answer (score 0):

Use following and all null value item will be last

```
SELECT * FROM warehouse ORDER BY ISNULL(level), level ASC;
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55f5d/2)